# `glossaries` package won't accept some symbols generated via `graphicx`

Tags: graphics, symbols, glossaries

I'm having issues with the `glossaries` package. For some reason, it just will not accept even simple symbols constructed via certain commands, *e.g.* from `graphicx`. Consider the following MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{
    amsmath,
    graphicx,
    glossaries, % <— changing the order does not help
}

\newglossaryentry{naturals}{
    sort={N},
    name={\ensuremath{N}},
    description={The set of naturals, $\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$.}
}
\newglossaryentry{meinzeichen}{
    sort={Symb},
    % name={a\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{I}b}, % <— from graphicx package. Glossaries won't accept it.
    name={test}, % <— obvs works.
    description={A special operation.}
}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
    \printglossaries

    \section*{Main test}
    Consider the set $N=\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$.\glsadd{naturals}
    Now consider the relation \glsadd{meinzeichen}
\end{document}
```

If one uncomments the commented line for the glossary entry, `meinzeichen`, a compile-error occurs:

```
! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 19.
<inserted text> 
                \fi
```

Obviously, I'm not going to dig into the `graphicx.sty` file and change things. Why won't glossaries accept symbols generated by `graphicx`? More importantly, how can I used commands like `\rotatebox` for symbols in glossary entries?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commands are fragile so need `\protect`

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{
    amsmath,
    graphicx,
    glossaries, % <— changing the order does not help
}

\newglossaryentry{naturals}{
    sort={N},
    name={\ensuremath{N}},
    description={The set of naturals, $\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$.}
}
\newglossaryentry{meinzeichen}{
    sort={Symb},
     name={a\protect\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{I}b}, % <— from graphicx package. Glossaries won't accept it.
    %name={test}, % <— obvs works.
    description={A special operation.}
}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
    \printglossaries

    \section*{Main test}
    Consider the set $N=\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$.\glsadd{naturals}
    Now consider the relation \glsadd{meinzeichen}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! Your solution worked. If I have defined my own macros, and these in turn are built from other macros, do I have to write `\protect` everywhere? If so, is there a way to „recursively“ *protect* a macro?